# How can I get type information about expressions in Java files?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, typechecking

By writing an "annotation processor" I can turn any Java text file into an abstract syntax tree and traverse it using a custom visitor (a subclass of [`TreePathScanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/tree/TreeVisitor.html)).

Unfortunately, [as I learned](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/doc/compilation-overview/index.html), the annotation processors are all run *before* the compiler's type-check stage.

What is the easiest way for me to get type information about Java expressions (assuming they are part of a complete, valid Java file)? I don't want to have to write my own type-checker.

Comment: What are you trying to do that needs type information about Java expressions?

Comment: I am trying to write a plugin for Sublime Text that tells me the type of whatever I have selected. (Plus maybe javadoc info, but that comes later.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking at it for some time, it seems that the answer is "you can't". Alas, I must seek an alternative solution. (The [Eclipse compiler API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600213/using-java-compiler-api-without-requiring-install-of-jdk) looks promising...)